# JQuery - Back to default function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu by clicking on a button "Show Menu".  When the dropdown shows, I click on "Menu 2", it shows a submenu.  After that, I let the dropdown menu and the submenu opened, then I hit the button, the menus are closed.

Now, I hit the button again, both the dropdown menu and submenu showing at the same time.  I want only the dropdown menu show.

Please give a hand.  Thanks!

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pa64g1s/)

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.myButton').on("click", function (){
      $('#first-menu').toggleClass("action")
    });
        $('.subMenu').click(function (){
      $('#second-menu').addClass("action1")
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
<button class="myButton">Show Menu</button>
</div>
<ul id="first-menu">
  <li>menu 1</li>
  <li class="subMenu">menu 2</li>
    <ul id="second-menu">
      <li>Sub Menu 1</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 2</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 3</li>
    </ul>
  <li>menu 3</li>
  <li>menu 4</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}
ul {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
#first-menu, #second-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: -170px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.action {
  left: 0 !important;
}
.action1 {
  left:70px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add remove class when hitting on the main show, also use toggle for the second one:

```
 $('.myButton').on("click", function (){
      $('#first-menu').toggleClass("action");
      $('#second-menu').removeClass("action1")

    });
        $('.subMenu').click(function (){
      $('#second-menu').toggleClass("action1")
    });
```